# Date Range Search Form Added to Navigation Form Does Not Function

Tags: forms, ms-access, navigation, ms-access-2010

I had another question.  I created a form to do a date range search from a table I have. The form functions perfectly as a single form.  I attempted to add it to my navigation form and it won't function within the nav form.  I just dragged it and dropped it into the form and when I attempted to do a date range search, I receive a runtime error '2491' stating that my form isn't bound to a table or query.  Why will it function when not in the nav form, but stops working once inserted into the nav form?  Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: You dragged a form into another form.  So now it's a subform of the form you dropped it into?  Research subforms, and parent/child linkages.

Comment: Thank you geeFlo, I will do that.